# mysql installer fails to recognize python 3.4

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, installation

I'm trying to istall mysql server on a windows 7 machine - that has python 3.4.3 installed. However, when trying to install the python connectors for 3.4, the installer fails to recognize the python installation, saying `python 3.4 is not installed`.

Has anyone solved this issue before? I'ts driving me nuts...

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to the murkiness, I had the same error with current version of MySql install when attempting with python 3.5 installed (which is the latest python download).  Long story short, I uninstalled python 3.5, installed python 3.4.4 (which interestingly didn't update PATH so I updated it manually) and reran installer and it found the python installation.

So my conclusion is the MySql installer is tied to certain versions of the add-on products which in this case meant specifically python 3.4

Comment: I'd like to confirm that. Just ran into this issue and solved it exactly like this. It did update PATH for me though, but you should change this option in the installer, second or third step, if I remember right. Here's the official link to the 3.4.4 64 bit, just in case: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/python-3.4.4.amd64.msi

Comment: Even more specifically, this worked for python 3.4.4. There are later versions 3.4, but those don't have Windows installers.

Answer (score 10):

just in case anyone else has this issue in future. Look at what bit version you have for Python 3.4. When I installed 64 bit version of Python 3.4, this issue went away.

Comment: I derped it and just clicked the first download button on python site. Turns out that I needed a very specific version number (3.5) and the 64 bit version. Thanks for your help. The 64 bit version clued me in on this.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar issue with Python 3.7.2.

In my case, the problem was that I tried to install the **64 bit** MySQL connector, but had the **32 bit** version of Python installed on my machine.

I got a similar error message:

> Python v3.7 not found. We only support Python installed using the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) [...]

The problem just went away by installing the **32 bit** MySQL connector instead.

Comment: this solved the problem for me. nothing else worked. 32-bit python works with 32-bit connector. good catch

Answer (score 2):

From my experience if you have both Py2.7 and Py3.4 installed when installing the mysql connector for py3.4 you will run into this issue. Not sure of the WHY but for some reason if you have py2.7 installed, the py3.4 mysql connector recognizes that version first and just assumes that you have py2.7 installed and does not recognize that py3.4 is installed.

The only way I have found around this is to uninstall py2.7 and then install the py3.4 mysql connector.  You can always install py2.7 again after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

I had 3.6.X version and it could not see it; I uninstalled it and installed 3.4.0 version and it passed the requirement. 
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and have fixed it. Using a Windows 7 PC and I already had multiple versions of Python installed.

1. Uninstalled all versions of Python from my PC
2. Uninstalled the failed MySQL install
3. Restarted PC
4. Re-installed Python 3.7 64-bit (the currently required version for MySQL)
5. Installed the Python 3.7 MySQL Connector ***separately*** through the link below
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
6. Once that was installed, restarted the MySQL install
7. The MySQL Installer window will open and already show the  Python 3.7 MySQL Connector in the list of products
8. Click "Add" at the top-right and select all of the products you want and then install them
9. You should then be able to complete the MySQL setup

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an similar answer.  The correct answer is that there is a bug in the mysqlconnector MSI.  When python installs, it creates a registry entry under HKLM Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6-32\InstallPath  however, the MSI for mysqlconnector is looking for installation path in the registry Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6\InstallPath as part of the RegLocator/registrypath variable.

Use ORCA to edit the MSI, change the RegLocator so that -32 is in the path.  It will install now without error or changes to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with python 3.4, all I did was installed python 3.4 version for ***all users***. and added system variable as per [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). it worked for me!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the 64bit version of whichever version of Python you are running. It can be downloaded from here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
Just had the same problem and this solved it for me. I also uninstalled all previous versions of Python before running the mysql setup

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem until I discovered I had installed python based in another architecture (32b). MySQL required 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Python 3.7 when trying to install MySQL in Windows 10. It was fixed by installing the 64-bits version of Python, not selected by default when going to https://www.python.org/downloads/.

I found it in https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3-amd64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler work around:

`pip install mysql-connector-python`

Is the same package that MySQL is having trouble installing. Just use pip to install it.

Next, go back to the installation style and select "Manual" instead of "Developer". They are identical, but "Manual" allows you to remove packages. Just remove the "Connector/Python" package from the list to be installed.

Carry on with the install, you're done.